# OOP C# Instance field not saving data

Tags: c#, oop

I have a set of instance fields inherited from class `G481Vars` by object `G481Var`.

```
G481Vars G481Var = new G481Vars();
```

The values of the instance fields are assigned to through this function

```
    private void AssignValuesG481()
    {                       
        HtmlInputText[] G481Inputs = new HtmlInputText[13]  //Create an explicit array of type HtmlInputText to handle elements of input boxes on G481 tab.
        {
            G481Disp_Txt, G481IniVel_Txt, G481FinVel_Txt, G481Acc_Txt,
            G481Time_Txt, G481Force_Txt, G481Mass_Txt, G481Weight_Txt,
            G481Press_Txt, G481Dens_Txt, G481Energy_Txt, G481Area_Txt,
            G481Vol_Txt
        };
        double[] G481List = new double[13] //Create an explicit array of type double that stores the instance fields of class G481Vars
        {
            G481Var.Disp, G481Var.IniVel, G481Var.FinVel, G481Var.Acc,
            G481Var.Time, G481Var.Force, G481Var.Mass, G481Var.Weight,
            G481Var.Press, G481Var.Dens, G481Var.Energy, G481Var.Area,
            G481Var.Vol
        };  
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) //Perform the iterative loop
        {
            if (G481Inputs[i].Value != "")
            {
                double.TryParse(G481Inputs[i].Value, out G481List[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `G481Vars` is Defined as:

```
public class G481Vars
{
    public double Disp { get; set; }
    public double IniVel { get; set; }
    public double FinVel { get; set; }
    public double Acc { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
    public double Force { get; set; }
    public double Mass { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Press { get; set; }
    public double Dens { get; set; }
    public double Energy { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
    public double Vol { get; set; }
}
```

However when i try and access these instance fields from another function `CalculateG481_Click` They always return `0`, even though they are assigned to before hand.

```
protected void CalculateG481_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AssignValuesG481();
    TempInputDebugField.Value = Convert.ToString(G481Var.Disp); //This always returns 0 in the field, even though <>0 was put into the disp input field and assignvariables run.
}
```

When I put the `TempInputDebugField` code into the `AssignValuesG481`  function it returns the correct value. Any ideas on what is going on with the instance field?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you name your classes something more meaningful hurts my eyes just looking at it. and have you even used the debugger ?

Comment: What makes you think they got assigned ? maybe there was an exception that never surfaced ? or maybe You're just looking on the wrong instance ?

Comment: double is a value type not a reference type , your assignment doesn't change the doubles stored in the G481Var variable but changes the values in the G481List

Comment: This is a physics calculator and so G481 is the module name that this section applies for, sorry for the horrible names :D @MethodMan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you think that setting the value of an element of `G481List` will forward that value on to the corresponding property of `G481Var` that was used to initialize the array.  That is not true.  all it does is change the values within the array.

You'll need to set the values of the instance explicitly.  You *could* use reflection to set the properties dynamically, but with only 13 properties it would be much safer and cleaner to just set them explicitly:

```
G481Var.Disp   = double.Parse(G481Inputs[0].Value)
G481Var.IniVel = double.Parse(G481Inputs[1].Value)
G481Var.FinVel = double.Parse(G481Inputs[2].Value)
G481Var.Acc    = double.Parse(G481Inputs[3].Value)
G481Var.Time   = double.Parse(G481Inputs[4].Value)
G481Var.Force  = double.Parse(G481Inputs[5].Value)
G481Var.Mass   = double.Parse(G481Inputs[7].Value)
G481Var.Weight = double.Parse(G481Inputs[8].Value)
G481Var.Press  = double.Parse(G481Inputs[9].Value)
G481Var.Dens   = double.Parse(G481Inputs[10].Value)
G481Var.Energy = double.Parse(G481Inputs[11].Value)
G481Var.Area   = double.Parse(G481Inputs[12].Value)
G481Var.Vol    = double.Parse(G481Inputs[13].Value)
```

From there you can use `TryParse` to better handle bad values, you can try using reflection to reduce duplicate code (at the expense of compile-time safety), etc.  The point is to get something that *works*, then find ways to make it *better*.  You can always go back to less "elegant" code if you get tired or stuck trying to refactor it.

Comment: Thanks, I originally had this method of explicitly defining them, but later on I have arrays of more than 50 input boxes and I was looking for another way of assigning them, and so created the code in the OP

Comment: If you want to avoid this type of code you _could_ use reflection to "map" the boxes to properties, but you can;t use an array as a "conduit" for these values since the array will store the value and not a reference back to the property.

Comment: Side note - "OP" == "Original Poster" which is you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. Silly mistake really! Side note: I always thought OP was interchangeable with original post, when said by original poster :O my bad! +1

Comment: No worries - "question" is generally how you refer to the original post.  Not a huge deal, just wanted you to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) //Perform the iterative loop
    {
        double val;
        if (G481Inputs[i].Value != "")
        {
            double.TryParse(G481Inputs[i].Value, out val);
            G481List[i] = val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No this cannot work. Double is a value type. Assigning the result to the list doesn't change the properties of the G481Var

Comment: This doesn't change the results at all = all it does it use an intermediate variable that is used to set the value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

double is a `valuetype`, so when you parse the strings the values are stored only in the array. You will have to assign this values to `G481Var` properties:

```
double value;
if (double.TryParse(G481Disp_Txt.Value, out value)
    G481Var.Disp = value;
```

Do this for each property and should works fine

Comment: Should be out value, not out double. :D